# How to implement templated function with "subtemplated"

Tags: c++11, c++14

I have a function which the declaration is

```
template<typename T> T get(int x);
```

What I want to achieve is to implement a version where the return type is a templated class (a.k.a chrono::time_point)

I tried

```
template<typename clock> std::chrono::time_point<clock> get(int x) {
  // implementation
}
```

But this doesn't match with the declaration. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: As of C++11, template functions cannot be partially specialized. I doubt they can be in C++14 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize a function.

You can route a function template through a traits/function object class to do what you want, however.

```
namespace details {
  template<class T>
  struct get {
    T operator()(int x) {
      // code
    }
  };
  template<class clock>
  struct get<std::chrono::time_point<clock>> {
    using T = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;
    T operator()(int x) {
      // code
    }
  };
}
template<class T> T get(int x) {
  return details::get<T>{}(x);
}
```